# Preserve new line characters of data from TextBox to SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using Multi-line TextBox through which users will be able to enter data which will be saved on to the SQL Server 2008 database. There is an other process, which reads this data from the table and writes to a text file.

Problem:
If the data entered by users in text box contains `<Enter>` from keyboard, it is saving to the database with some spaces replacing the `<Enter>`.

Some how if I read the same data to a text box on webpage, it is being displayed properly.

But, if my second process that reads the data from database and prints to a text file, it is not keeping the text format properly. It is not retaining the `<Enter>` in the data being printed to text file.

Can any one help me how to retain the `<Enter>` in the text file being generated?

Comment: You need to show us the code that is generating the text file.

Comment: You should also note that SSMS does not usually display a line break in the output of a select statement, hence the reason it looks like they have been replaced by a space in the database.  However, if you load your text into a variable and then pass it to PRINT you will see that they are still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your `<Enter>` is being retained in the database since it works correctly when you output to the textbox again.

My guess is that the problem is either in the process writing them to the textfile stripping out CR and LF characters or your text reader isn't achknowledging them.

If you open the text file in Notepad++ and then go to view --> show symbol and make sure "Show End of Line" is checked you should be able to see if the CR and LF characters at the end of the line are preserved when written to the text file.

Comment: I second this. I have had related issues with getting user input to display properly when output as text on a web page.  You have to parse the stored string and replace the line breaks with <br /> or <p>...</p> tags in order to preserve the entered format.  But if you load the string back into a text box you see it rendered as originally entered, i.e. the line breaks are still there.

Comment: @Rozwel if you wrap the text in `<pre></pre>` the line breaks are displayed.

Comment: True.  I was thinking about places where I had built data driven pages where users with the correct permissions could edit the content.  In those situations I have to worry about more than just line breaks so the other tags work better.  If it is just a matter of displaying plain text with the spacing that was entered then the pre tags should work well.